# GCP logger filter missing fields

Tags: node.js, http, google-cloud-platform, google-logging

My application runs in NodeJS in GCP Cloud Run, it uses the REST API and logs the request object. I'm trying to filter out results with missing field `locationId` in `jsonPayload.req.body.destination` object in GCP logger.

I tried this filter:

```
NOT jsonPayload.req.body.destination:locationId
```

or

```
NOT jsonPayload.req.body.destination=locationId
```

but it doesn't work.

I'm looking for some results like this:

```json
destination: {
addressLine1: "my address"
contactEmail: "john@doe.com"
postalCode: "74757"
}
```

you can see the `locationId` is missing there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I found a solution, this should work for my case:

```
-jsonPayload.req.body.destination.locationId:*
jsonPayload.req.body.destination:*
```